# Template not found error when using jinja2 and webapp2 on Apache2 with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I'm banging my head against a wall right now.  I've been fighting with this for hours, and I'm just done for the day.  I'm hoping someone out there can clue me in.

I'm receiving this error from my server after configuring apache with mod_wsgi to try and run a webapp2 with jinja2 Python application locally (not using the gae developer server) so I can move away from gae for some local projects I have in mind and not have to learn a new framework at the moment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/exmqa/main.py", line 39, in get
self.render_template('index.html', name=self.request.get('name'))
File "/var/www/exmqa/main.py", line 35, in render_template
self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 812, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
```

TemplateNotFound: index.html

I have no idea why.  The app was working fine on gae, and I followed instructions I could find online to move it over, including installing webapp2, jinja2, patch, and webob.  I have tried about 2 dozen different suggestions or ideas that sprang from reading on SO and other sites, and have still not figured out why I am continuing to see this.

For reference, here's my current main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/exmqa/modules')
import dmpautomation

template_dir = '/templates'
loader = FileSystemLoader(template_dir)
environment = Environment(loader=loader)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))

class Home(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_template('index.html',     name=self.request.get('name'))

class Automation(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_template('dmpauto.html', name=self.request.get('name'))
    def post(self):
        IP = self.request.get("ipaddress")
        self.response.write(IP)
        callable(dmpautomation.autotest(IP))

class Soak(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_template('dmpsoak.html', name=self.request.get('name'))







app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Home),
    ('/dmpauto', Automation),
    ('/dmpsoak', Soak)
], debug=True)
```

Anyone have any suggestions of what I need to do differently to get jinja2 templating working in an Apache2 with mod_wsgi environment running Python and webapp2?  Is there some config for Apache that I'm not aware of and have been missing?  Something, anything, this is getting ridiculous.

Thanks in advance for anything you might be able to suggest.

EDITED: Adding the contents of my exmqa.conf file (Apache config file) for whatever information that may provide.  The two `<Directory>` sections were added from information I found here and there trying to debug this. From everything I've been able to find thus far, the Alias lines I added should be all that's needed.  I'm wondering if there's a permissioning issue somewhere that allows me to access the files directly, but not the running instance of Apache.  I'd find that weird, since apache2 is running as root and www-data, and I would think that would give it access to the world.  Obviously, Apache is not my expertise.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGICallableObject app

<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerName exmqa
    ServerAlias exmqa.corp.uievolution.com

    ServerAdmin mcole@uievolution.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exmqa
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/exmqa/modules/main.py

    <Directory /var/www/exmqa>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/exmqa/templates>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /css/ /var/www/exmqa/css/
    Alias /images/ /var/www/exmqa/images/
    Alias /js/ /var/www/exmqa/js/
    Alias /scripts/ /var/www/exmqa/scripts/
    Alias /templates/ /var/www/exmqa/templates/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Maybe, instead of `template_dir = '/templates'` try to give it a full path `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')` (or something like that)?

Comment: To confirm if the `templates_dir` value is indeed your problem (my suspicion as well) symlink your `templates` dir under `/` temporarily (to make the `/templates` path valid) - if this makes the error go away it is indeed confirmed, it's just a matter of finding the right value. It might be a bit tricky if you have a complex/unusual app dir structure. For example I had to resort to tweaks involving `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to make the same code in a shared lib symlinked into multiple modules work properly on both local dev and GAE.

Comment: I had originally tried `code`template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')`code`, and I just tried that again just now.  Same result.  My templates directory already resides in  my server root, so no need to symlink it.  I have also tried it using `code`template_dir = '/var/www/exmqa/templates'`code` (the full server side path to the templates directory) with no luck.

Comment: More investigation found a few things.  First, I had my apache configured incorrectly.  I added a config file for exmqa and had my WSGIScriptAlias in the root folder.  As such, according to the documentation I found, that blocks anything BUT that (in my case main.py) from doing anything at that level.  Since all of my directories live at that level, that effectively hosed me.  Following the instructions to configure around that, I added `Alias /templates/ /var/www/exmqa/templates/` to the config file (along with a similar statement for css, js, images, & script folders also)

Comment: I can now access everything through the browser at URL/path/file.html, but I am still receiving not found errors for the templates.  Even though I can plainly see that they are in fact there and are now accessible directly in the browser.  I'm sure there's something absolutely stupid that I'm overlooking here.

Comment: access from the browser via the web server is a different story (static file access), your problem is related to your code accessing the filesystem, internally (it's not making requests to the server to get the templates).

Comment: Another thought: I see you're using a cached `self.jinja2` but I don't quite see how you configure it (i.e. where to you map the global `loader` and `environment` vars to self.jinja2 whose `render_remplate()` you invoke).

Comment: Is that this part you're referring too?  Have I misconfigured something here?              `template_dir = '/templates'  
loader = FileSystemLoader(template_dir)  
environment = Environment(loader=loader)  
  
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):  
    @webapp2.cached_property  
    def jinja2(self):  
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)  
  
    def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):  
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))`

Comment: Sorry, the formatting on that sucks, and I can't seem to be able to do anything about it.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm referring to. I can't figure out how the `jinja2.Environment` instance (customized with a `jinja2.FileSystemLoader` instance) is actually mapped to the webapp2-cached `jinja2.Jinja2` instance returned by `jinja2.get_jinja2()`. So I ended up using the `jinja2.Environment` instance explicitly (have yet to check if I can't cache that one instead).

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved